# Calculate Percentage population from Vector Grids

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, vector-grid, analysis

I have a vector grids layer of population (shapefile). Each grid represents population in that grid and have the following attributes:

`Area`
`Population`

I want to calculate and display the percentages of population and their respective area of coverage.

For example: which grids (highlight those grids) constitutes the x% of the population (to indicate the area where we should deploy our resources for maximum coverage), how many are they and what is the total area (effectively, number and sum of the attributes of selected grids).

I am trying to explore something that can help in QGIS but haven't found anything yet. Can anyone please recommend something (any tool, script or software as I am not bound in terms of software).

Comment: That sounds fairly interactive, perhaps a python addin tool might work for you https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/creating-an-add-in-tool.htm

Comment: Please decide whether it's QGIS or ArcGIS Desktop (if so whether it's ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap) that you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: I have just removed the tags for arcGIS.